# some confusion in upper traingular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$1$. What is the dimension of the subspace of all real $n \times n$  matrix of upper triangular matrix?

$2$. What is dimension  of  all real $n \times n$  matrix  of upper  triangular ?

Is both option

$1)$

and

$2)$  having same dimension?

Any hints/solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2), let be $S$ the space of upper triangular matrix $M_n(R)$. So the dimension is equal to the elements in that space that can be a base (every matrix with 1 in any single place) so the dimension will be dim($S$)$= n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+3+2+1 = {n(n+1) \over 2 }$; of course it depends on $n$.

For sure dim($S$) < $n*n$ in this case.
Every element of this kind can be a base remember!

For 1), is the same as 2), the "subspace" requirements seems identical to question 2).

Comment: .@alessar .is this method  same for lower triangular ??

Comment: The matrix is $n*n$, so the dimension is the same; they are simply symmetrical respect the principal diagonal

Comment: thanks u  got its

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

An upper triangular matrix is defined by $N=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ elements.